# How many memory latency cycles per memory access type in OpenCL/CUDA?

Tags: memory, cuda, opencl, latency, nvidia

I looked through the programming guide and best practices guide and it mentioned that Global Memory access takes 400-600 cycles. I did not see much on the other memory types like texture cache, constant cache, shared memory. Registers have 0 memory latency.

I think constant cache is the same as registers if all threads use the same address in constant cache. Worst case I am not so sure.

Shared memory is the same as registers so long as there are no bank conflicts? If there are then how does the latency unfold?

What about texture cache?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latency to the shared/constant/texture memories is small and depends on which device you have. In general though GPUs are designed as a throughput architecture which means that by creating enough threads the latency to the memories, including the global memory, is hidden.

The reason the guides talk about the latency to global memory is that the latency is orders of magnitude higher than that of other memories, meaning that it is the dominant latency to be considered for optimization.

You mentioned constant cache in particular. You are quite correct that if all threads within a warp (i.e. group of 32 threads) access the same address then there is no penalty, i.e. the value is read from the cache and broadcast to all threads simultaneously. However, if threads access different addresses then the accesses must *serialize* since the cache can only provide one value at a time. If you're using the CUDA Profiler, then this will show up under the serialization counter.

Shared memory, unlike constant cache, can provide much higher bandwidth. Check out the [CUDA Optimization](http://nvidia.fullviewmedia.com/GPU2009/1002-gold-1086.html) talk for more details and an explanation of bank conflicts and their impact.

Comment: Is it still worth using constant cache if for example, all threads access a 1000 floats? Would that be like a 1000 reads from a register? The guide said the usage of constant cache in this way scales linearly right?

Comment: If all threads access the *same* value in any given iteration of a loop then you can use constant cache. The constant cache will provide some benefit due to spatial locality (on Fermi the L1 cache may achieve the same thing but this leaves L1 free for other data). Having said that, I target Fermi mostly and never use `__constant__`, I just use const a lot and let the compiler figure it out! For example in your case I would pass the kernel arg as `const float * const myfloatarray`. I would recommend always running the Visual Profiler to check for serialization just in case you missed something.

Comment: One might add, that cache lines are 128byte (32byte) for L1 (L2), so we are talking about addresses falling into the same lines (not necessarily same adresses). Some numbers on other latencies can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744101/fermi-l2-cache-hit-latency).

Answer (score 8):

For (Kepler) Tesla K20 the latencies are as follows:

> Global memory: 440 clocks
>   Constant memory
>       L1: 48 clocks
>       L2: 120 clocks
>   Shared memory: 48 clocks
>   Texture memory
>       L1: 108 clocks
>       L2: 240 clocks

How do I know? I ran the microbenchmarks described by the authors of [Demystifying GPU Microarchitecture through Microbenchmarking](http://www.stuffedcow.net/research/cudabmk). They provide similar results for the older GTX 280.

This was measured on a Linux cluster, the computing node where I was running the benchmarks was not used by any other users or ran any other processes. It is BULLX linux with a pair of 8 core Xeons and 64 GB RAM, nvcc 6.5.12. I changed the `sm_20` to `sm_35` for compiling.

There is also an [operands cost](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#operand-costs) chapter in PTX ISA although it is not very helpful, it just reiterates what you already expect, without giving precise figures.

Comment: I too am using Tesla K20, and I tried to run the same microbenchmark you mentioned. Were you able to run `global.cu` with no problems? I ask because I am facing an issue with illegal memory accesses - I have posted this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36416843/how-to-write-a-pointer-chasing-benchmark-using-64-bit-pointers-in-cuda). I was wondering if you made any changes to the kernel code to make it work for you?

Comment: @kv.333 It was some time ago. I remember there were some issues and not all the benchmarks ran. I don't remember which ones though.