# What are the measured latency values of an memory hierarchy in a example CUDA capable device?

Tags: cuda, benchmarking, latency

Even though [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4097635/how-many-memory-latency-cycles-per-memory-access-type-in-opencl-cuda) question is similar to mine, there still isn't any published latency values for the different types. I'd appreciate an actual measurement and an explanation of the methods and reasoning for their approach. Any CUDA capable discrete NVidia card would be ideal.

Things to measure:

1. Register
2. Shared Memory
3. Constant Cache Hit
4. Device Memory
5. Global Memory

Comment: [This paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5452013) is pretty much the gold standard benchmarking example for a CUDA GPU.

Comment: Want to make your comment an answer? That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This paper](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5452013) is pretty much the gold standard benchmarking example for a CUDA GPU. It exposes most of the information you are interested in by very thorough micro benchmarking, using the Tesla C1060/GTX 285 "GT200" class GPU.